# How much high iterative partitioning of the first inaccessible stage can be?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Working in $ZF$ + existence of an inaccessible ordinal.

Let $\kappa$ be the first inaccessible ordinal (i.e. the first regular ordinal that is a limit of regular ordinals).

Let *subpartition* of $X$ stand for a "subset of a partition of $X$".

> Question 1: Can we have a $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartition of $\mathcal P(V_{\kappa})$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartitions of $V_{\kappa}$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized?
>
> Question 2:If so, can we go up? i.e. have a $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartition of $\mathcal P^2(V_{\kappa})$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartitions of $\mathcal P(V_{\kappa})$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartitions of $V_{\kappa}$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized?
>
> Question 3:If so, then how long can we go up further? i.e. up to which finite ordinal $i$ we can have have a $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartition of $\mathcal P^i(V_{\kappa})$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartitions of $\mathcal P^{i-1}(V_{\kappa})$,..., whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized subpartitions of $V_{\kappa}$ whose elements are $V_{\kappa}$ sized?

Comment: How do you define an inaccessible? The definitions equivalent in ZFC are not equivalent in ZF. Also, do you have to use a notation which is widely used for the entire cumulative hierarchy for one of its stages?

Comment: Ok, corrected. Thanks!

Comment: If $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then it is a $\beth$-fixed point, and so $V_\kappa$ has size $\kappa$.

Comment: Well, you are referring throughout to "size $V_\kappa$", but this just means "size $\kappa$", and so your way of stating the problem is needlessly cumbersome.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, yes I know. That doesn't essentially change the question in any substantial manner. Anyhow I want to keep it as such, because I want the same question to work under absence of choice, for whatever the definition of inaccessible ordinal is.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins ok, I've edited my question to suite the more general quest I originally intended it to be for.